# How I can set my Views files(.html) resource from "webapp" to "resources" folder in SpringMVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to know how I can set my Views files(.html) resource from "webapp" to "resources" folder in SpringMVC project.

[this is my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/890zB.png)

Here is my config file code, now my .html files resource folder is in webapp folder, and I want to change it to resources folder.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("Controllers")
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("resources");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        springTemplateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {//to set viewer
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same problem. I need to transfer templates, css files and images from the webapp folder to the resources folder.
In search of an answer, I went through the code of stores that are publicly available on github.
I found a project in which all these resources are stored in the resources folder. As I understand it, another class is used there to configure the application. Here is the code. So far, I have not been able to make it work in my project, but I will dig in this direction.
Perhaps this will help you too.

package com.geekbrains.geekspring.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
//    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
//        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
//            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
//        }
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have solved the problem. I think you should be able to too. You only need to change one line of code.
My mistake was that when I specified the path in this line:
templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");

I thought I was specifying it in MyProjectName/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/
This is where my templates used to be.
But in fact, I specified the path in the server folder that is generated during compilation
based on the folders we created in src.
Now this folder is called "target". So, in fact, I pointed the way to
MyProjectName/target/shop/WEB-INF/views/

Now I have moved all my templates to MyProjectName/src/main/resources/templates folder
Since a new folder has appeared here, then on its basis in the "target" directory at startup
project generated a new folder along the path
MyProjectName/target/shop/WEB-INF/classes/templates

Accordingly, I indicated a new path following this logic
templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/templates/");

And everything worked!
It remains to transfer css and images.

[image: my project directory]

My config file

```
package ru.shop.three_d_print.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.shop.three_d_print")
@EnableWebMvc

public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Autowired
public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver()
{
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine()
{
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry)
{
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
}
```